# NoMethodError in RevisersController#new "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller

I want the user to have the ability to become a reviser! So they can get the feature of being a reviser if they fill out the form to become one!  I have a `has_one reviser` and the `user` is linked to `resource reviser` in the routes.rb.
Im getting this error! something that has to do with my reviser probably returning null from what I read online but I don't know how to not make it null from my `def new` in my reviser controller.

**reviser controller:**

```rails
class RevisersController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_reviser, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @reviser = current_user.reviser
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @reviser = current_user.reviser.build
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @reviser = current_user.reviser.build(reviser_params)

    if @reviser.save
      redirect_to @reviser,notice: "saved...."
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    set_reviser
  end

  def update
    set_reviser
    if @reviser.update(reviser_params)
      redirect_to @reviser,notice: "updated.."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

private 
def set_reviser
  @reviser = Reviser.find(params[:id])
end

  def reviser_params
    params.require(:reviser).permit(:description, :average_start, :average_end, :max_pages, :price_per, :active)
end
end
```

**new.html:**

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
 Create your reviser profile information
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="container">

  <%= form_for @reviser do |f| %>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="div.col-md-4 select">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>dsd</label>
    <%= f.input :description, label: false, class: 'controls',:input_html =>{:id => 'description'} %>
   </div>
    
   </div> 
  </div>
             <%= f.submit "Become Adviser", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Error report:**

`Started GET "/users/16/reviser/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-16 03:48:18 +0900
Processing by RevisersController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"16"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
  Reviser Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "revisers".* FROM "revisers" WHERE "revisers"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 16]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/revisers_controller.rb:15:in`new'

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for building is: current_user.build_reviser(params[:reviser])

Comment: Okay that went away, but now i get `undefined method revisers_path:` what should i put within the `build_reviser({})`?  Thanks!!

Comment: build_reviser(params[:reviser])

Comment: oh! and you'll want `<%= form_for(current_user, @reviser) do |f| %>` - because reviser is nested inside user!

Comment: that's a routing error you're getting. you need to include all the relevant parts of the route in your form_for, redirect_to, etc. In this case your route is `users/:user_id/revisers` so you need that user_id wherever you make a route or path.

Comment: yea so i enter the id of the user so my url looks like http://localhost:3000/users/16/reviser/new

Comment: undefined method `user_revisers_path' is the new error :( haha i think i have to edit the path for it?